# Removing a parent element in xml while keeping it's children using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to transform the following xml,

```
<pets>
    <Pet>
        <category>
            <id>4</id>
            <name>Lions</name>
        </category>
        <id>9</id>
        <name>Lion 3</name>
        <photoUrls>
            <photoUrl>url1</photoUrl>
            <photoUrl>url2</photoUrl>
        </photoUrls>
        <status>available</status>
        <tags>
            <tag>
                <id>1</id>
                <name>tag3</name>
            </tag>
            <tag>
                <id>2</id>
                <name>tag4</name>
            </tag>
        </tags>
    </Pet>
</pets>
```

in to this xml format.

```
<pets>
    <Pet>
        <category>
            <id>4</id>
            <name>Lions</name>
        </category>
        <id>9</id>
        <name>Lion 3</name>
        <photoUrl>url1</photoUrl>
        <photoUrl>url2</photoUrl>
        <status>available</status>
        <tag>
            <id>1</id>
            <name>tag3</name>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <id>2</id>
            <name>tag4</name>
        </tag>
    </Pet>
</pets>
```

I tried to write a template as follows, but it removes the parent element with it's children.

```
<xsl:template match="photoUrls"/>
```

How can this be done in xslt. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to work.  <xsl:template match="photoUrls">
  <xsl:copy-of select="photoUrl" />
 </xsl:template>, Still any feedback is appreciated. Is this the best way or are there other better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="photoUrls|tags">
       <!-- Apply identity transform on child elements of photoUrls/tags-->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This works when I don't have any namespaces in my xml but fails to remove the tags when I have namespaces (soapenv) in my xml. How can I modify it to work?

Comment: Got it, I added [local-name()] before the tag and it works.

Comment: @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan Would you mind sharing the updated code?

Answer (score 3):

The following xslt does the job,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="photoUrls">
        <xsl:copy-of select="photoUrl" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tags">
        <xsl:copy-of select="tag" />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But if you have any other way of doing this please don't hesitate to post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="photoUrls|tags">
    <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Don't copy attributes if you're not copying the parent element.